# Is there an equivalent to 'minYear'/'maxYear' for months in a date input in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I would like to limit the dates available to those in this and next month.

So far, I know I can specify a minimum and maximum year, which is part of what I need.

```
$this_month = new DateTime('now');
$next_month = new DateTime('next month');

echo $this->Form->input('date', 
    array(
        'minYear'  => $this_month->format('Y'),
        'maxYear'  => $next_month->format('Y'),
    )
);
```

Is there a similar way in which I can specify the months I need?

Comment: You could manually create your dropdowns.

Comment: Pass in array of months that you want as an `$options` into a `$this->Form->select('date', $options)`

Comment: Thanks @DavidYell , what would the $options look like in this particular situation?

Comment: @mark Do you mean creating different inputs for the months, days and years?

Comment: It would be just a plain array of months `array(1=>'Jan',2=>'Feb',3=>'Mar',9=>'Oct',11=>'Nov')`

Comment: Thank you @DavidYell this would work if i had my date broken into different inputs (for month, day and year)

Comment: Oh you aren't sticking with the CakePHP conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways of solving this problem neither is as simple as you would probably like:

First:

Create a class that extends the FormHelper class and create your own month function that adds the ability for this.

Second:

You can pass in an array of month names, so you could generate only the list of months that you wish an end user to select and pass that into your month function:

`<?php echo $this->Form->month('months', null, array('monthNames' => array(1 => 'Jan', 2 => 'Feb', 3 => 'March'))); ?>`

Will generate a month selector with only those three months in the drop down.

Comment: Thank you jtyost2, this is what I ended up doing and it works just fine :)