# How to set min or max date limit in CakePHP form?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my current date form input, I have the parameter:

```
'maxYear' => date('Y')
```

This lets me limit the max year to this year, but I also need to limit the date selection so users cannot select a date in the future. Using `maxYear` only allows limiting the year, **but I also need months and days**.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819950/is-there-an-equivalent-to-minyear-maxyear-for-months-in-a-date-input-in-cake

Comment: @InigoFlores It's similar, but I wouldn't consider it duplicate.  That answer only refers to limiting the month select and IMO requires a completely different answer.

Comment: @Dave you are right, `day` is not addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not something you can do with the Form Helper (or the HTML form options even if you'd wrote them manually).

---

**The problem:**

If you limit the month to say, 1-7 (if we're currently in July), the user would be unable to select the previous year of any of those months.

---

**The solution:**

Use [JavaScript `onchange` validation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp).  When the field(s) change date, check the selected date against your required date range, and give notification if it fails.  (see [jQuery's `.change()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/change/) if you're using jQuery)

(Then verify on the back-end, as well of course, as JavaScript can easily be manipulated)